# view does not display the array data when using $scope

Tags: angularjs

I have the following snippet of code that does not work in my view:

```
  myapp.controller('AddChoreController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
      var choreList = this;
      $scope.choreList.chore = [{ name: 'Gun Running', frequency: 'As Needed', allowance: '$1000', id: 0 },
                                { name: 'Party Planning', frequency: 'Wednesdays', allowance: 'Free', id:1}];
```

When I take the $scope off of `choreList.chore` my view displays the data correctly.

My view simply does this:

```
                        <tr ng-repeat="chore in chores.chore">
                            <td>{{chore.name}}</td>
                            <td>{{chore.frequency}}</td>
                            <td>{{chore.allowance}}</td>
                        </tr>
```

I would like array to be available later in the screen and automatically load the new entries as they get added.

As you can tell I'm still very new to angularjs so any suggestions (with links to tutorials) are very appreciated.

Comment: you haven't shown the entire html template, but it seems like you are using the Controller As syntax, by the use of `var choreList = this;`...  generally the Controller As syntax is meant to eliminate the dependency on `$scope`, and in your case, `var choreList` is not the same object as `$scope.choreList`.  It appears you may have used `ng-controller='AddChoreController as chores'` in your view, but it's not obvious here

Comment: @Claies - you are right I have the following: ng-controller="AddChoreController as chores"> - So based off of your comment does that mean I don't need $scope and that my array that i'm trying to access already has access to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing Techniques here.  You are using the Controller As Syntax, which is an alternative to `$scope`.  When using Controller As, the controller object itself is presented as a property on `$scope`, allowing you to implicitly add items to the `$scope` as properties of the controller *rather than* as objects themselves.  The controller does not need to reference `$scope` at all in this scenario.

Your controller code can be simplified to:

```
myapp.controller('AddChoreController', function () {
    var choreList = this;
    choreList.chore = [{ name: 'Gun Running', frequency: 'As Needed', allowance: '$1000', id: 0 },
                       { name: 'Party Planning', frequency: 'Wednesdays', allowance: 'Free', id:1}];
...
```

The `chore` array here will be a property of the controller, and reference able directly from the view via `chores.chore`

Based on this method for handling properties and scope, it might make sense to rename your properties.  I might do something like:

```
myapp.controller('AddChoreController', function () {
    var chores = this;
    chores.choreList = [{ name: 'Gun Running', frequency: 'As Needed', allowance: '$1000', id: 0 },
                       { name: 'Party Planning', frequency: 'Wednesdays', allowance: 'Free', id:1}];
...
```

then, in your view:

```
<div ng-controller='AddChoreController as chores'>
    <tr ng-repeat="chore in chores.choreList">
     ....
</div>
```

This more clearly expresses the pluralization of the elements.

Comment: thanks.  I think this answers my question.  However I think I have a ton more follow-up questions now...

Comment: to be honest, I might recommend naming your properties a bit differently, to make it easier to trace their origin. I'm going to edit my answer with a recommended approach.

Answer (score 0):

1. In controller try to name your list just choreList and attach it to scope:

```html
$scope.choreList= [{ name: 'Gun Running', frequency: 'As Needed', allowance: '$1000', id: 0 }, { name: 'Party Planning', frequency: 'Wednesdays', allowance: 'Free', id:1}];
```

2. In view inside ngRepeat directive iterate through the array (which is attached to scope)

   `ng-repeat="chore in choreList"`